# Spring @Around > Behaviour of arguments

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm just following the `@Around` [example provided by spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example), and had a quick question about the behaviour of passing arguments to the underlying method ([their explanation wasn't clear to me](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)).

If I wrap my Aspect around a method which takes arguments, do I have to explicitly pass the arguments into the `proceed(Object[])` method like so... (or is this just for overriding parameters?)

```
return pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs());
```

Or will calling `proceed` with no args, implicitly pass through the original arguments to the underlying method?

```
return pjp.proceed();
```

Long story short, I don't want to change the behaviour of calling the existing methods. I'm currently writing a quick test to prove the behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. Calling `proceed` with no args, implicitly pass through the original arguments to the underlying method.
From a user point of view `proceed()` and `pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs())` do the same.
You'll need to call `pjp.proceed(new Object[] {...})` only if you want to override arguments.

For Spring based runtime weaving take a look at [`MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java#L83-L98) and [`ReflectiveMethodInvocation::invocableClone`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/400749667aad7511f2e33fbd5b4a1f103619a554/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/framework/ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java#L202-L239) respectively, and you'll see that both `ProceedingJoinPoint::proceed` methods calling 
`ReflectiveMethodInvocation::invocableClone(arguments)` under the hood.